# Zend 3 Direct Sql Query Execute

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

Zend 3 has default Table gateway functions like Select,Insert,Delete and Update but i want to execute Direct Sql Prepared Statement queries Like Below

```
$Qry = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tableNames['UserTable']." WHERE LOWER(Email) = '".strtolower($Email)."' AND Password = '".md5($Password)."'";
            $statement = $this->adapter->query($Qry); 
            $SelectCond = $statement->execute();
```

above code working fine with zend 2.4 but is there any possibilites like execute direct queries on zend 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you get $adapter here, if not try to get adapter.

```
$adapter = $this->getServiceManager()->get('adapter-name'); // 
$results = $adapter->query($Qry)->execute();
```

Or,

```
$results = $adapter->query($Qry, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

if you leave the second Parameter of `$adapter->query($Qry)`, empty you will get a `\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface` which you need to execute.